# ECONNREFUSED when trying to connect to redis via node using docker-compose

Tags: node.js, redis, docker-compose

I'm trying to switch over to docker, for some reason my Node.js application won't connect to redis running on docker.

This is my docker compose:

```
version: "3"
services:
  chatty-backend:
    container_name: chatty-backend
    build: ./
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/chatty-backend
    command: npm start
    working_dir: /usr/src/chatty-backend
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    links:
      - redis
      - mongo
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - mongo

  mongo:
    image: mongo:bionic
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"

  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    command:
      redis-server
```

This is where I'm connecting to redis:

```
import * as Redis from 'ioredis';

const redis = new Redis({ host: 'redis', port: 6379 });

export default redis;
```

Also tried `new Redis('redis://redis:6379')`

I'm getting this error currently:

```
 Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
   at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1056:14) {
     errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
     syscall: 'connect',
     address: '127.0.0.1',
     port: 6379 
}
```

Comment: as far as i remember, links are deprecated for docker compose v3. try running without links settings in ` chatty-backend` service definition. Also, do you get error you mentioned when you start app in docker container? or when you start it on host machine? Error means redis client tries to connect to redis server listening on `127.0.0.1:6379`, not on `redis:6379` - probably, you defined badly something in config of your nodejs app?

Comment: I don't think links are deprecated yet but you should be using networks instead of links as it is a planned deprecation. But as you can see, chatty-backend is not trying to connect to `redis` but rather `127.0.0.1` which will need to be fixed in your code (which thinks it is connecting to the local machine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue caused by `graphql-redis-subscriptions`.
I forgot to pass the updated confifg.